# How to train the same Form Recognizer Model?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

We're trying to increase the accuracy of the form recognizer model by providing more data for the model to be trained on. We've tried to provide more than 5 files for the initial training but it is timing out.

We have reviewed the documentation provided and don't see a way for us to train the same model again.

Is it possible to train the same model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form Recognizer Cognitive Service does not support a retrain functionality on the same model. However, you can call a /train request on the newer dataset which creates another model. There is a limit on the size of the dataset of 4MB (more information on the requirements can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set#general-input-requirements)). Would suggest you to decrease the number of documents used for training and try again.